# Magento 1.9 doesn't override core controller

Tags: magento

I want to override the controller: "ProductController" from Mage/Catalog.

Namespace: Ziny

Module: AutomaBrasil

My module is on local folder.

Resources like Helpers, Models and Blocks, I override without errors; but controllers I can't.

**Ziny/AutomaBrasil/etc/modules/Ziny_AutomaBrasil.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ziny_AutomaBrasil>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ziny_AutomaBrasil>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Ziny/AutomaBrasil/code/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ziny_AutomaBrasil>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ziny_AutomaBrasil>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <automabrasil>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ziny_AutomaBrasil</module>
                    <frontName>automabrasil</frontName>
                </args>
            </automabrasil>
            <catalog>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <automabrasil before="Mage_Catalog">Ziny_AutomaBrasil</automabrasil>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Ziny/AutomaBrasil/code/controllers/ProductController**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';

class Ziny_AutomaBrasil_controllers_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        die('Dark Souls');
    }
}
```

Nothing happens. The controller hasn't been overriden.

Someone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Are you using modman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change following in your code.

```
Ziny/AutomaBrasil/code/etc/config.xml
```

to

```
Ziny/AutomaBrasil/etc/config.xml
```

and

```
Ziny/AutomaBrasil/code/controllers/ProductController
```

to

```
Ziny/AutomaBrasil/controllers/ProductController
```

**Update :** I don't use modman but by searching on the modman commands on internet following should work for you to deploy.(Please comment if I am wrong.)

```
modman deploy Your_Extension_Path
```

Comment: How did I miss that in OP's question - well spotted!

Comment: Muk, I found the solution. I'm using modman, so I just needed a modman deploy, because the "controllers" folder wasn't in my module root. Could you please edit your answer to reflect that solution, so I can accept it?

Comment: @GuilhermeDeFavere  Please check the updated answer.